# Merging pandas dataframes, alternating rows without soritng rows

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I'm trying to mimic an spss style correlation table in my Pandas output to make it easier to read for supervisors who are used to seeing matrices laid out this way (and are annoyed that I don't use SPSS anymore because it's harder for them to read).

This means that there is a table where the p-value is placed directly above the correlation coeff in the table. I have easily produced both the p-values and the coeffs and saved each into a separate dataframes like the ones below.

```
pvals
    T   4    Rw    Af
T |0.00|0.05|0.24|0.01
4 |0.05|0.00|0.76|0.03
Rw|0.24|0.76|0.00|0.44
...

rs
    T   4    Rw    Af
T |1.00|0.65|0.28|0.44
4 |0.65|1.00|0.01|0.03
Rw|-0.03|0.01|1.00|0.32
...
```

What I'd like to do is make a table where the two dataframes are merged without changing the order of the index. It would look like

```
T |P |0.00|0.05|0.24|0.01
  |r |1.00|0.65|0.28|0.44
Rw|P |0.05|0.00|0.76|0.03
  |r |0.65|1.00|0.01|0.03
...
```

Now, I understand that if my columns had alphabetically ordered names I could use something like

```
pd.concat([pvals, rs]).sort_index(kind='merge')
```

However, my columns are named with descriptive, non-ordered names and so this doesn't work because it reorders the index into alphabetical order. I also know that

```
df.corr()
```

will produce a matrix like the rs example I've given above but this is not what I'm looking for.

If anyone has any advice I'd really appreciate it.

Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use helper `MultiIndex` with `np.arange` and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True`, add `keys` parameter for `P`, `r` values, sorting by `range`s, remove this level and last change order of levels by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
s1 = pvals.set_index(np.arange(len(pvals)), append=True)
s2 = rs.set_index(np.arange(len(rs)), append=True)

df = (pd.concat([s1, s2], keys=('P','r'))
        .sort_index(kind='merge', level=2)
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .swaplevel(0,1))
print (df)
         T     4    Rw    Af
T  P  0.00  0.05  0.24  0.01
   r  1.00  0.65  0.28  0.44
4  P  0.05  0.00  0.76  0.03
   r  0.65  1.00  0.01  0.03
Rw P  0.24  0.76  0.00  0.44
   r -0.03  0.01  1.00  0.32
```

**Asker Edit**

This answer worked once the code was changed to

```
s1 = pvals.assign(a = np.arange(len(pvals))).set_index('a', append=True) 
s2 = rs.assign(a = np.arange(len(rs))).set_index('a', append=True)

df = (pd.concat([s1, s2], keys=('P','r'))
        .sort_index(kind='merge', level=2)
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .swaplevel(0,1))
```

which was recomended by the answerer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time. 

When I run this code however, I get the error: 

```numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_index'```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @KevOMalley743 - What is your pandas version? For me it working perfect in pandas 0.25.0.

Comment: @KevOMalley743 - If not working, here is alterantive for first 2 lines of code `s1 = pvals.assign(a = np.arange(len(pvals))).set_index('a', append=True)` and `s2 = rs.assign(a = np.arange(len(rs))).set_index('a', append=True)`